# Unable to persist object using Spring/JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have written code to persist an object using spring boot / JPA and Hibernate.

NOTE: I have changed the actual names of the classes for confidentiality.

TableA object is not getting persisted when I call, TableADaoService.create method. The instance of TableADaoService is autowired in the class where I am calling create.

What is that I am missing? I spent nearly 2 days to read through various materials and SO postings. I am fairly new to this topic and this is my first code that uses spring boot / JPA and Hibernate to persist an object.

I am able to write the object into file using GSon and that's looks perfectly fine. But the write to mysql is not working. I am not getting any exception as well. It is just that when I do a get call to read from the DB, I see that it doesn't exist.

Relevant properties of application.properties as below:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MySchema
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=XXX    
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings = false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.sql.init.mode=always
```

Below is the definition of my Class: (Ignored the getter/setters for brevity)

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "TABLEA", uniqueConstraints = {
                    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "ID")})
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "creationTime", "updatedTime" }, allowGetters = true, ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class TableA implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
        private Long id;
    
        @Column(name = "NAME", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 100)
        private String Name;
     
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
        @JoinTable(name="A_B", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="A_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")}
            , inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="B_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")})
        private List<TableB> cList = new ArrayList<>();
    
        @Temporal(value=TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        @Column(name="CREATED_TIME")
        private Date creationTime;
        
        @Temporal(value=TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        @Column(name="UPDATED_TIME")
        private Date updatedTime;
     }
```

````
TableB class is as below: (Ignoring getter/setters for brevity) 

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLEB", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "ID")})
@CacheConfig(cacheNames={"houseDatacache"})
public class TableB implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    private String Name;
    private int HouseNumber;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="B_C", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="B_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")}
    , inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="C_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")})
    //@JoinColumn(name="planet_id")  
    private Set<C> cSet = new HashSet<>();

    @Temporal(value=TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="CREATED_TIME")
    private Date creationTime;

    @Temporal(value=TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="UPDATED_TIME")
    private Date updatedTime;
}
```

Below is the definition of TableADao class:
```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public class TableADao extends AbstractJpaDao<MyChart> {
    public TableADao() {
        super();
        setClazz(MyChart.class);
    }
}
```
AbstractJpaDao as below:

```
public abstract class AbstractJpaDao<T extends Serializable> {
    private Class<T> clazz;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "entityManagerFactory")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public final void setClazz(final Class<T> clazzToSet) {
        this.clazz = clazzToSet;
    }

    public T get(final Long id) {
        return entityManager.find(clazz, id);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<T> findAll() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("from " + clazz.getName()).getResultList();
    }

    public T create(final T entity) {
        entityManager.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    }

    public T update(final T entity) {
        return entityManager.merge(entity);
    }

    public void delete(final T entity) {
        entityManager.remove(entity);
    }

    public void deleteById(final Long entityId) {
        final T entity = get(entityId);
        delete(entity);
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.xxx
")
public class EntityManagerFactoriesConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EntityManagerFactoriesConfiguration.class);

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emf.setDataSource(dataSource);
        emf.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"com.xxx"});
        emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        return emf;
   }
    
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactienter code hereonManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

MyChartService class is as below:

```
@Service
public class TableADaoService {
    
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TableADao.class);
    private TableADao dao;
     
    public TableADaoervice(TableDao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    public TableADao get(final Long id) {
        return dao.get(id);
    }
    
    @Transactional
    public TableADao create(final TableADao result) {
        logger.debug("In TableADao service save profile:");
        if(result != null) {
            Date date = new Date();
            result.setCreationTime(date);
        }
        return dao.create(result);
    }
   }
```
````

UPDATE 1: After enabling debug on, I am seeing below error that the transaction is getting rolled back but not sure why though.

```
2022-03-06 23:36:04.728 DEBUG 36389 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-1] o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager            : Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(428197716<open>)] for JPA transaction
2022-03-06 23:36:04.729 DEBUG 36389 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-1] o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager            : Creating new transaction with name [com.xxx.service.TableAService.create]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2022-03-06 23:36:04.729 DEBUG 36389 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-1] o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager            : Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@370f2e18]
2022-03-06 23:36:04.730 DEBUG 36389 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-1] c.m.s.TableAService                     : In TableA service save profile:
2022-03-06 23:36:04.730 DEBUG 36389 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-1] o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager            : Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(428197716<open>)] for JPA transaction
2022-03-06 23:36:04.730 DEBUG 36389 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-1] o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager            : Participating in existing transaction
2022-03-06 23:36:04.730 DEBUG 36389 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-1] c.m.d.AbstractJpaDao                     : in create... persist...
2022-03-06 23:36:04.734 DEBUG 36389 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-1] o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager            : Participating transaction failed - marking existing transaction as rollback-only
2022-03-06 23:36:04.734 DEBUG 36389 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-1] o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager            : Setting JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(428197716<open>)] rollback-only
2022-03-06 23:36:04.734 DEBUG 36389 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-1] o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager            : Initiating transaction rollback
2022-03-06 23:36:04.734 DEBUG 36389 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-1] o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager            : Rolling back JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(428197716<open>)]
2022-03-06 23:36:04.736 DEBUG 36389 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-1] o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager            : Not closing pre-bound JPA EntityManager after transaction
20
```

UPDATE 2:

When I ran the application in debug mode in Eclipse, I got the below exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.xxx.entity.TableA; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist:
```

The child TableB should NOT already exist in the DB and hence I am not sure why I am seeing this error. I tried to change Cascade.ALL to Cascade.PERSIST and still the same error.

What is that I am missing? Also, why did I not see this exception when I didn't run in debug mode?

UPDATE 3: I made some progress. While trying to persist TableA which has unidirectional OnetoMany relationship with Table B, I am getting below exception:

Can someone help me understand what is going on here?

NOTE: I am using the profile ID as the ID for both Table A and Table B. I am no longer auto generating it.

```
2022-03-07 21:00:28.349 DEBUG 39462 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-2] o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager            : Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(1155241674PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[com.xxx.entity.TableC#20], EntityKey[com.xxx.entity.UserProfile#47], EntityKey[com.xxx.entity.UserProfile#46]], collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2022-03-07 21:00:28.370 DEBUG 39462 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-2] o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager            : Creating new transaction with name [com.xxx.dao.TableADao.create]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,-java.lang.Exception
2022-03-07 21:00:28.378 DEBUG 39462 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-2] o.h.e.t.i.TransactionImpl                : begin
2022-03-07 21:00:28.384 TRACE 39462 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-2] j.i.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor : Preparing to begin transaction via JDBC Connection.setAutoCommit(false)
2022-03-07 21:00:28.395 TRACE 39462 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-2] j.i.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor : Transaction begun via JDBC Connection.setAutoCommit(false)
2022-03-07 21:00:28.401 TRACE 39462 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-2] cResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl : ResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl#afterBeginCallback
2022-03-07 21:00:28.407 DEBUG 39462 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-2] o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager            : Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@4f165f83]
2022-03-07 21:00:28.416 TRACE 39462 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-2] o.h.e.s.IdentifierValue                  : ID unsaved-value strategy UNDEFINED
2022-03-07 21:00:28.422 TRACE 39462 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-2] o.h.e.i.EntityState                      : Transient instance of: com.xxx.entity.TableA
2022-03-07 21:00:28.429 TRACE 39462 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-2] o.h.e.i.DefaultPersistEventListener      : Saving transient instance
2022-03-07 21:00:28.434 DEBUG 39462 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-2] o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener        : Generated identifier: 47, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.Assigned
2022-03-07 21:00:28.442 TRACE 39462 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-2] o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener        : Saving [com.xxx.entity.MyChart#47]
2022-03-07 21:00:28.448 TRACE 39462 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-2] o.h.e.i.Cascade                          : Processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST for: com.xxx.entity.TableA
2022-03-07 21:00:28.455 TRACE 39462 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-2] o.h.e.i.Cascade                          : Done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST for: com.xxx.entity.TableA
2022-03-07 21:00:28.767 TRACE 39462 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-2] o.h.e.i.WrapVisitor                      : Wrapped collection in role: com.xxx.entity.TableA.TableB
2022-03-07 21:00:28.775 TRACE 39462 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-2] o.h.e.s.ActionQueue                      : Adding an EntityInsertAction for [com.xxx.entity.TableA] object
2022-03-07 21:00:28.782 TRACE 39462 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-2] o.h.e.s.ActionQueue                      : Adding insert with no non-nullable, transient entities: [EntityInsertAction[com.xxx.entity.TableA#47]]
2022-03-07 21:00:28.790 TRACE 39462 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-2] o.h.e.s.ActionQueue                      : Adding resolved non-early insert action.
2022-03-07 21:00:28.822 TRACE 39462 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-2] o.h.e.i.Cascade                          : Processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST for: com.xxx.entity.TableA
2022-03-07 21:00:28.832 TRACE 39462 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-2] o.h.e.i.Cascade                          : Cascade ACTION_PERSIST for collection: com.xxx.entity.TableA.TableB
2022-03-07 21:00:28.855 TRACE 39462 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-2] o.h.e.s.CascadingAction                  : Cascading to persist: com.xxx.entity.TableB
2022-03-07 21:00:28.880 TRACE 39462 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-2] o.h.e.i.EntityState                      : Transient instance of: com.xxx.entity.TableB
2022-03-07 21:00:28.887 TRACE 39462 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-2] o.h.e.i.DefaultPersistEventListener      : Saving transient instance
2022-03-07 21:00:28.908 DEBUG 39462 --- [http-nio-8085-exec-2] cResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl : JDBC transaction marked for rollback-only (exception provided for stack trace)

java.lang.Exception: exception just for purpose of providing stack trace
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.markRollbackOnly(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:324) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.markRollbackOnly(TransactionImpl.java:203) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.markForRollbackOnly(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:428) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.handlePersistenceException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:297) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:790) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:752) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadingActions.java:298) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:510) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:434) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:543) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:474) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:437) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:459) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:293) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:135) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) [hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:760) [hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:746) [hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362) [spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at jdk.proxy2.$Proxy158.persist(Unknown Source) [?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
```

Comment: why ain't you persisting data using
`JpaRepository<Table, PrimaryKey-DataType>`

Comment: What is MyChart? `public class TableADao extends AbstractJpaDao<MyChart> {`? What is returning Dao by id `public TableADao get(final Long id) {`?

Comment: @MuhammadAwaisRashid, I tried JpaRepository and that didn't work either.

Comment: @AndriySlobodyanyk, it is a typo. MyChart is actually TableA and get returns TableA.

Comment: `c.m.d.AbstractJpaDao                     : in create... persist...` where does it come from? How do you create/save entities? Don't you mind to fix typos and update the question?

Comment: @AndriySlobodyanyk, I already fixed the typo that I have spotted. **in create... persist** came from AbstractJpaDao create method just before calling entityManager.persist.

Comment: I still don't see the log call with `in create... persist...` at the provided code. Also, could you confirm that after fixing the typo `TableADaoService` still accepts and returns `TableADao` instead of `TableA` at `create` and `get` methods? Do you understand the difference between `TableADao` and `TableA` classes?

Comment: I added the log after I shared my code. As noted earlier, it was just before calling entityManager.persist in AbstractJpaDao.create. I solved this problem after fixing multiple issues. Some of them are as below:

Comment: When I ran this code in debug mode, I found out that I had multiple issues and one of them include moving the @ Transactional to AbstractEntityDao and removed class level @ Transactional in the service class. I also had issues with id in TableB. Also included "readOnly = false" for create method of AbstractEntityDao.